# Postgres SQL: Find exceptions when using an in clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, temp-tables

I am running the following (Postgres) SQL against a table containing a list of ids.  The SQL below will return all the ids found in the list* below.

```
select id from table
where id in (1,2,3,5,8,11,13,22,34,55);
```

How can I return ids which are contained in the list but not in the table?  I realise I can do this using a temp table (with the list in it) and a left outer join but is there a quicker/cleverer way?

Comment: where are those id if not in the table? another table?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: id is one of the columns on the table (e.g. table contains 2 columns: id integer, description: text).  It is a generic question as it applies to any table with an id column.  The reason for asking is I was given a list of ids and asked which were missing.  The example list of ids is the (Fibonacci number) example ids.  I want to quickly find them without creating a temp table of the ids.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if arbitrary ids exist in your table, use a CTE and exists

```
WITH ids (id) AS ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(5),(8),(11),(13),(22),(34),(55)
)
SELECT id
FROM ids 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM table WHERE table.id = ids.id)
```

*note1: alternatively use a `left join` instead of `WHERE NOT EXISTS`*

*note2: it may be necessary to add the appropriate type casts*

Or you can use `EXCEPT`

```
WITH ids (id) AS ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(5),(8),(11),(13),(22),(34),(55)
)
SELECT id
FROM ids 
EXCEPT ALL 
SELECT id FROM ids
```

Comment: That's fantastic.  Exactly what I wanted.  Many thanks.